# Issue with navigation in sammyJS javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sammy.js

I am using `sammy.js` plugin in my single page application. The plugin is not working, whenever user tries to navigate in the page it is showing the following error on console :

```
[Tue Dec 04 2012 17:48:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] #main 404 Not Found get /page_home  
Error
arguments: undefined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "404 Not Found get /page_home "
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: undefined
__proto__: d
```

What is this issue and how can it be fixed ?

**EDIT**

Sammy configuration code:

```
 var app = $.sammy('#main', function () {
        this.get('#/:name', function () {
            var id = this.params['name'];
            $.trim(id);
            var flag = true;

            if ($("#main").hasClass("presentation")) {
                $.each(slides, function (i, v) {
                    if ($(v).attr("class") == id) {
                        ScanNavigationD(id);
                        flag = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (flag) {
                    ScanNavigationD($(slides[0]).attr("class"));
                }
            }
            else if ($("#main").hasClass("printdoc") || typeof $("#main").attr("class") == "undefined") {
                $.each(Pages, function (i, v) {
                    if ($(v).attr("class") == id) {
                        ScanNavigationD(id);
                        flag = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (flag) {
                    ScanNavigationD($(Pages[0]).attr("class"));
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        app.run();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Tom, Can you post your sammy configuration code?

Comment: Have you made sure you have properly linked your page to the plugin API? e.g. <script src="../path_to/sammy.js"></script>

Comment: @ShaltNot the error he pasted here is comming from sammy.js, so the include must be correct

Answer (score 2):

@tom-rider the problem is the app.run called without argument.
The sammy app.run function accept a start_url argument to set (via the _setLocation method) the app current location before call _checkLocation method to check if url is changed...
So  try to change

```
app.run();
```

with

```
app.run('#/');
```

this work for me.

Follow this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeyramone76/qqu56/5/) for a working demo and look at the console: no error!

Answer (score 0):

will this simple code work?

```
var app = $.sammy('#main', function () {
    this.get('#/:name', function () {
        alert(this.params['name']);
    });
});

$(function () {
    app.run();
});
```

if this small code alerts 'page_home' there is something wrong with your script inside:
then you should be able to answer these questions: where is the ScanNavigationD-Function? where are the "slides"/"Pages" - arrays defined?

EDIT:

ok, i did another test at my computer. thats what i did:

1. created a html-document
2. included first jQuery then sammy.js

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">

   <script src="sammy.js" type="text/javascript">
3. i filled the vars and functions i asked for with dummy-content:

   <script>

   var ScanNavigationD = function() {},
       slides = ['slide1', 'slide2'],
       Pages = ['page1', 'page2'];

   <script>
4. then i copy pasted your code into my html-document.

   <script>
     //your code
   <script>
5. then i created the div-main container:

everything worked. the last thing i see you are doing wrong is, that you are just on your local filesystem.

sammy.js seems to need a webserver to run! at least localhost!

```
file://...
```

WILL NOT WORK

Comment: see everything after "EDIT:"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are sending in `page_home` as a parameter when running the script which resolves to a 404 not found error. Try look for 'page_home' throughout your files, recursively to find where this is coming from.